# How to avoid duplicate code with a helper-method for shared REST-operations like GET and DELETE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dry, code-duplication

I have two methods

- `methodOne` (e.g. for a GET on questionaire)
- `methodTwo` (e.g. for a DELETE on questionaire)

Both have almost same lines of code.

IntelliJ also underlines the code and shows a warning:

> duplicated code fragment

#### `methodOne`

```java
@Override
public QuestionnaireDTO methodOne(long projectManagerId, long questionnaireId) {

    //the part I want to write into a helper method
    ProjectManager projectManager = projectManagerRepository.findById(projectManagerId).orElseThrow(
            () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("ProjectManager", "id", projectManagerId));

    Questionnaire questionnaire = questionnaireRepository.findById(questionnaireId).orElseThrow(() ->
            new ResourceNotFoundException("Questionnaire", "id", questionnaireId));

    if(!questionnaire.getProjectManager().getId().equals(projectManager.getId())){
        throw new QuestionnaireApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Questionnaire not belonging to Project Manager");
    }
    // end of helper method

    // return of methodOne 
    return mapToDto(questionnaire);
    
}
```

#### `methodTwo`

```java
@Override
public QuestionnaireDTO methodTwo(long projectManagerId, long questionnaireId) {

    //the part I want to write into a helper method
    ProjectManager projectManager = projectManagerRepository.findById(projectManagerId).orElseThrow(
            () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("ProjectManager", "id", projectManagerId));

    Questionnaire questionnaire = questionnaireRepository.findById(questionnaireId).orElseThrow(() ->
            new ResourceNotFoundException("Questionnaire", "id", questionnaireId));

    if(!questionnaire.getProjectManager().getId().equals(projectManager.getId())){
        throw new QuestionnaireApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Questionnaire not belonging to Project Manager");
    }
    // end of helper method

    // return of methodTwo 
    return questionnaireRepository.delete(questionnaire);
    
}
```

#### Questions

I want to write the duplicated part of the code (enclosed in comments above) into a helper method.
I want to avoid duplicate code but I'm not sure how to structure the helper method.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: @Anon edited the question but the user knittl solved it for me I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just move the code 1:1 to a new method:

```
public QuestionnaireDTO methodTwo(long projectManagerId, long questionnaireId) {
    return mapToDto(findById(projectManagerId, questionnaireId));
}

public QuestionnaireDTO methodOne(long projectManagerId, long questionnaireId) {
    return questionnaireRepository.delete(findById(projectManagerId, questionnaireId));
}

private QuestionnaireDTO findById(long projectManagerId, long questionnaireId) {
    ProjectManager projectManager = projectManagerRepository.findById(projectManagerId).orElseThrow(
            () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("ProjectManager", "id", projectManagerId));

    Questionnaire questionnaire = questionnaireRepository.findById(questionnaireId).orElseThrow(() ->
            new ResourceNotFoundException("Questionnaire", "id", questionnaireId));

    if(!questionnaire.getProjectManager().getId().equals(projectManager.getId())){
        throw new QuestionnaireApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Questionnaire not belonging to Project Manager");
    }

    return questionnaire;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I expected :) It's such an easy solution it's kind of embarrassing not coming up with it on my own. I really need to up my Java game. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Next to DRY principle this `findById` helper is also beneficial for REST-implementations because some operations on a resource like  `DELETE /questionaire/{id}` and `GET /questionaire/{id}` often share semantics and exception-handling like 404 etc.

Comment: @hc_dev thank you. I will consider doing that for the coming sprint of our app. And thank you for editing the initial question. Helps me to ask my questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The shared code can return a `Questionnaire` object or throw a `ResourceNotFoundException`:

```java
private Questionnaire findQuestionnaire(long projectManagerId, long questionnaireId) {
    ProjectManager projectManager = projectManagerRepository.findById(projectManagerId).orElseThrow(
            () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("ProjectManager", "id", projectManagerId));

    Questionnaire questionnaire = questionnaireRepository.findById(questionnaireId).orElseThrow(() ->
            new ResourceNotFoundException("Questionnaire", "id", questionnaireId));

    if (!questionnaire.getProjectManager().getId().equals(projectManager.getId())){
        throw new QuestionnaireApiException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Questionnaire not belonging to Project Manager");
    }
    
    // return questionnaire if both IDs are valid
    return questionnaire;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Basically the same anser as the one from user knittl but he was a bit more specific with the implementation of the helper method into the two functions. I needed it to be that specific still a junior :-/ Gave you an upvote though.

Comment: .. and `throws QuestionnaireApiException`. Would also help to mention the  applied technique's name or show how to use the error-showing IDE.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** When IntelliJ warns about "duplicated code fragment" then *Extract Method* refactoring is a solving IDE-shortcut.

---

Always pays-off to add more context like used IDE and shown error-message to the question.

Before posted answers (from [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75111783/5730279) and [mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75111572/5730279)) show you the resulting code: definition of extracted helper-method `findById` and its usage in given methods `methodOne` and `methodTwo`.

This answer shows how IntelliJ supports you to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and avoid duplication (most other IDEs have similar functions).

#### Extract Method refactoring

A common refactoring method, to either break code up and improve readability or to avoid duplication and follow DRY is: [*Extract Function*](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractFunction.html) or *Extract Method*

IntelliJ IDEA has an action for [Extract Method](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-method.html):

> The **Extract Method** refactoring lets you take a code fragment that can be grouped, move it into a separated method, and replace the old code with a call to the method.

To use the refactoring technique *Extract Method* select the code-block you want to extract (e.g. code enclosed in your given comments). Then you can choose among 4 ways as you prefer:

- hover over the code (sometimes bulb-symbol appears) and press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> to show **Intention Actions**
- right-click to open the **context-menu**, then navigate to: refactor, extract-method
- **Find action** (Win/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd>) by name "Extract Method"
- press the **keyboard-shortcut** for *Extract Method* action <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + M</kbd> (Win/Linux, different on Mac)

See also: [3 Ways to Refactor Your Code in IntelliJ IDEA | The IntelliJ IDEA Blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/12/3-ways-to-refactor-your-code-in-intellij-idea/#Extract_Method).

#### Intention Actions help on errors in IntelliJ

Since this error-message is shown as a result of IntelliJ's [Code Inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-problems.html), it might be prepared to help you solving it.

In many cases (like here) these 1-2 steps are the quickest way from error to fix:

1. [Jump to issues/errors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#navigate-errors-warnings) in code pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> (Win/Linux). Those issues/errors can also be found by yellow gutter-marker or a red gutter-marker and bulb-symbol showing up.
2. Use [Intention Actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html): Click on the bulb-symbol or press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> (Win/Linux) to show IntelliJ's *Intention Actions*. Select "Extract method from duplicate code"

See also: [IntelliJ IDEA Documentation: Analyze duplicates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-duplicates.html) to learn about IDE-support in finding and fixing duplication.

#### When and how extract-method in IntelliJ works

First a modal-dialog opens where you can enter the name of the method.
Usually IntelliJ suggests the name and parameters that are used as input.

More important is the return-value or output. A method or function can only be extracted if either no or exactly one single return-value or output can be determined. In you case `Questionnaire questionnaire` is the singular output.

After confirming the dialog, your extracted helper-method was created by IntelliJ and all previous locations from where the code was extracted are replaced by a respective method-call.